# Use Google Spreadsheet as data source for Chart.js

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, chart.js, google-sheets-api

Is it possible to use a Google spreadsheet as a datasource when using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/)?

I'd like to use Chart.js to create a line chart with multiple lines, and I'd like the user to be able to view all lines at once or select certain ones to display. Seems fairly simple to do with Chart.js, however, I'm wondering how to make the chart updatable for the client.

The client already has a dataset in Google spreadsheet that they update regularly, so I'd like to have the chart on the website update along with the spreadsheet.

Would I just need to export the Google spreadsheet as a JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3/data you can retrieve google spreadsheet data using API and present the returned data in Chart.js.